# Makefile error in C with same function

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I want use "Makefile" in my project which im working on socket programming. I have two simple .c files but they have their own main function. And makefile returns an error because of these two main functions.

I have one main function in server.c file and one main function in client.c

## ERROR

> gcc server.o client.o -o output -lpthread client.o: In function
>   `main': client.c:(.text+0x0):`main' için birden fazla tanım
>   server.o:server.c:(.text+0x78): ilk burada tanımlanmış collect2:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile:4: recipe for target
>   'output' failed make: *** [output] Error 1

## MAKEFILE

```
all: output

output: server.o client.o
    gcc server.o client.o -o output -lpthread

server.o: server.c
    gcc -c server.c

client.o: client.c
    gcc -c client.c

clean:
    rm *.o
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work like that. You'll need two outputs, ala

```
all: server client

server: server.o
    gcc server.o -o server -lpthread

client: client.o
    gcc client.o -o client -lpthread
```

This is because your program can only have one `main`. What are you trying to do that you want to compile both .c files into one executable?

Comment: It doesnt work, im sorry. Error is missing seperator?

Comment: The lines that begin with `gcc` should start with a tab, not spaces. I'm guessing you might have ended up with spaces.  :)

Comment: Thank you alot. Yeah i forget to change them from space to tab. Problem solved